# get document.text from webbrowsercontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

How do i get the document.text from the webbrowser control in WPF?

This control doesn't have this property anymore in WPF. I have looked in the msdn articles and there is nothing about it.

Also, googling this up didn't give me any results on this control in WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the browser has finished navigating, you can call a method like this...

```
public static void GetPageContent(WebBrowser wb, string fileName)
{
    mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass dom = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)wb.Document;
    Task t = new Task(() => File.WriteAllText(fileName, dom.body.innerHTML));
    t.Start();
}
```

This method places the entire page into a standard ASCII file and you can parse out content according to your need.

To use this method, you will need to include a reference to the Microsoft.mshtml assembly, which should be located in the .NET tab of the 'Add Reference' dialog.  As shown, I spawn off a separate thread in order to keep the UI perky, but this is optional.

For the case where you simply want the string returned to the client, you can use this method...

```
public static string GetPageContent(WebBrowser wb)
{
    return ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass) wb.Document).body.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: The user wants to have the innerHTML, so that part is good. But @Yustme doesn't wanted it to be written to file?

Comment: hi garry, thanks! i did had a compiler error about the HTMLDocumentClass that cannot be embedded. after googling, i found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/f938ac22-08cf-430e-b13f-c63b50f1943c[this][1] post that fixed it. Can i also get the absolutePath like this? because they left that one out too in webbrowser control in WPF.

Comment: nice! looks like you know your way with the webbrowser control. any chance you know how to prevent it from loading flash and javascript etc too? ;o

Comment: well i have asked this question before. but you want me to add the relevant tags for you to answer it? :D